# What is electron precipitation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electrons, resource-recommendations

I'm completing a dissertation project and the only source which explains what [electron precipitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_precipitation) actually is is linked [here](https://vlf.stanford.edu/research/lightning-induced-electron-precipitation-ground-observations), from the wikipedia sources. However, when investigating the sources this site has claimed to use, none of them actually say what is written here, or give any explanation on what electron precipitation actually is.

So, my question is what is electron precipitation, and what are good sources for learning about electron precipitation?

Comment: So what is it about the info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_precipitation  which doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the source given for wikipedia's definition is not a scientific article nor do the sources in the source account for what was said

Comment: Have you been through the other sources listed in the Wikipedia article? In particular source [2] looks like it might have the definition you're seeking.

Comment: @electronpusher I had looked though all the sources in the wikipedia article and found nothing, but I double checked the 2nd source and at no point do they define precipitation or electron precipitation I'm afraid. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research I found this paper https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2005RG000174 (Frey 2007), which outlines precipitation (electrons being freed from the magnetosphere and hence moving into Earth's upper atmosphere).

I consider this satisfactory.

Comment: Which is **exactly** what the Wikipedia page says.  Your skepticism about reliability of science/math Wiki pages is unfounded.

Comment: I have no skepticism about wikipedia lol I need scientific articles for referencing in my dissertation

Comment: Please don't "lol" on this site.